# Proving $\frac{\sec\theta+\csc\theta}{1+\cot^2\theta}=\frac{\sec\theta+2\sin\theta}{1+\cot\theta}$

Tags: trigonometry

I don't know how to prove this. Can someone help？

> $$\frac{\sec\theta+\csc\theta}{1+\cot^2\theta}=\frac{\sec\theta+2\sin\theta}{1+\cot\theta}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of $c:=\cos\theta,\,s:=\sin\theta$, the left-hand side is $$\frac{1/c+1/s}{1+c^2/s^2}=\frac{s(s+c)}{c(s^2+c^2)}\stackrel{*}{=}\frac{s(s+c)}{c},$$while the right-hand side is$$\frac{1/c+2s}{1+c/s}=\frac{s(1+2sc)}{c(s+c)}\stackrel{*}{=}\frac{s(s+c)^2}{c(s+c)}=\frac{s(s+c)}{c}.$$The only tough part is occasionally spotting when to use $1=s^2+c^2$, at the starred $=$ signs.

Comment: thanks a lot，i can prove it now

Answer (score 0):

Multiply the numerator and denominator of the right side by $\cos\theta$ to find

$$\dfrac{1+2\sin\theta\cos\theta}{\cos\theta+\sin\theta}=\cos\theta+\sin\theta$$

The left side $$\dfrac{(\sin\theta+\cos\theta)\sin^2\theta}{\sin\theta\cos\theta}$$

The two sides will be equal only if $\sin\theta=\cos\theta$

Answer (score 0):

Use $1+\cot^2\theta = \csc^2\theta$

$$\frac{\sec\theta+\csc\theta}{\csc^2\theta} = \sin\theta(\tan\theta+1) = \sin\theta(\tan\theta+1)\cdot\frac{1+\cot\theta}{1+\cot\theta}=\frac{\sec\theta+2\sin\theta}{1+\cot\theta}$$

where the last equality follows from the fact that

$$\sin\theta(\tan\theta+\cot\theta) = \frac{\sin^2\theta}{\cos\theta} + \cos\theta = \sec\theta$$